# Simulated Metrics. retina 3.5 full sreen don t work

Tags: iphone, ios6, simulation, autolayout

If I set retina 3.5 full screen in the View Controller/ simulated metrics, its works fine if i simulate in iPhone( retina 3-5 inch), but if i try in iPhone ( retina 4 inch ) there aren t the 2 black strips on the top and bottom, my view is elongated and it s fill up the whole retina 4 inch. Autolayout is on! I didn t modify anything in Xcode. I reinstalled my macbook, and xcode just because of this, and it s still not working.

What I want: I don t want an autorisezing application, only just a 3.5 inch app, and if I run this app on an iPhone 5 it s still works fine with 2 black strips on the top and bottom, no distortion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you got a Default-568h@2x.png image as the loading screen for the Retina 4-inch device? If so, remove it and you should find your app only runs as a 3.5-inch app.